# 7-Zip not working from the DOS prompt or command line?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I have 7-Zip installed, and it works from Windows, but not from the DOS prompt or command line:

```
7z e  max_logs_can_messages.tgz
```

Yields:

```
'7z' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: It's `7za.exe`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: 7za e max_logs_can_messages.tgz yields same error message

Comment: @Blender: 7zFM.exe is the 7-Zip File Manager. 7z.exe is the command-line version of 7-Zip. 7z.exe uses 7z.dll from the 7-Zip package, that's used by 7zFM.exe too. 7za.exe (a = alone) is the standalone version of 7-Zip. 7za.exe supports only 7z, lzma, cab, zip, gzip, bzip2, Z and tar formats. 7za.exe doesn't use external modules. tl;dr: 7z.exe or 7za.exe will both work at the command line, but 7za.exe doesn't have any external dependencies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need to add the binary to your machine's PATH

See more here: http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html

Comment: Half right - definitely need the path variable, or to be in that directory, or to use the fully qualified path of 7z.exe, but with Windows, you do not need to include the extension on `exe` files.

Comment: Updated my answer, [Joe Enos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/111266/joe-enos), thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can either copy 7-Zip to a well-known path like these:

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

or you call 7-Zip with the full path:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
```

Or you do the thing [Screenack said](https://superuser.com/questions/581587/7-zip-not-working-from-the-dos-prompt-or-command-line/581588#581588) ;)

Comment: using the full path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" in place of the 7z in the command worked like a charm for me. When I tried to set the path like some of these other solutions show, I just got a new error message. Thank you for this!!

Answer (score 3):

**while zipping in cmd or git bash - getting error like**

```
7z:command not found
```

`solution:`

- install 7z in your machine
- set the path in Environment Variables -> User Variables
- path -> edit -> new (add the path - C:\Program Files\7-Zip) -> OK

`Now to use 7z in git Bash`

- Go to C:\Program Files\7-Zip and copy 7z.exe file
- Go to C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin and paste 7z.exe file

Now, you will be able to use 7z with Git Bash

Answer (score 2):

You need to register 7-Zip as a system PATH environment variable. An easy way to do this in Windows 7 & 8 is to run this from the command line:

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the 7-Zip folder to your `PATH`:

```
setx /M path "%path%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\"
```

Alternatively, for [Easy 7-Zip](http://www.intowindows.com/easy-7-zip-free/):

```
setx /M path "%path%;C:\Program Files\Easy 7-Zip\"
```

Comment: If you want only a temporary change to the PATH, I believe you could run the following command between the quotes instead: "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\" .
See superuser.com "What is the difference between SETX and SET in environment variables in Windows" for the difference between the set and setx command.

Comment: Messed up my system path when run from Powershell.  Guess this is only meant for running from cmd prompt?

Answer (score 0):

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Program Files\7-Zip")

where you should replace C:\Program Files\7-Zip with your 7-zip folder.

this way you can use "7z" as a command.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.