# Trying to use a bat file but I get the error "7z is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, 7-zip

I assume I need to make Windows recognize 7z as something it can use but I don't know how.

I searched for answers and this one here said that I need to add the binary to my machine's PATH but I don't know how to do that or if this is even correct:
[7-Zip not working from the DOS prompt or command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/581587/7-zip-not-working-from-the-dos-prompt-or-command-line/581588#581588)

I would really appreciate if someone could walk me through what I have to do to be able to use this bat file.

Answer (score 3):

Issuing the command `path /?` will give you some hints. But adding the line `SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\7-Zip"` as the first line in yor BAT file should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that but I get the same result. I also noticed that I have the same message for "robocopy" which is also something the bat file tries to do. Somehow windows doesn't seem to recognize any of the commands in the batch file.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use SET PATH=... instead of just simple path command. Could you please try using that?

Comment: Thanks, I copied SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\path\to\your\7zip-bin into the first line of the bat file and I still receive the same error. 7z is not recognized.

Comment: I've just installed 7zip and updated my answer with the real path.

Comment: It should be emphasised that you add the _directory_ path (up to the last back-slash, excluding `7z.exe`), not the full file path.

Comment: I copied this as the first line in the bat file:
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip
Nothing changes. 7z is still not recognized. What do you mean by "the directory path" as opposed to "the full file path"?

Comment: Put the path between double quotes: SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\7-Zip"