# Using 7z command Windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, 7-zip

I have recently been trying to use 7z in Powershell but seem to be struggling to get it to work. I thought the issue would've just been that I didn't have 7-Zip added to my environment variables, but after trying everything listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/581587/7-zip-not-working-from-the-dos-prompt-or-command-line) I am still coming up empty handed. To be clear, the main thing I have tried is adding the path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" to my "Path" system environment variable. However, when I try to run it:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 7z
7z : The term '7z' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ 7z
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (7z:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This is essentially what I end up with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Concerning harrymc's comment, yes the file does exist and it has been verified. For instance, when I run "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" it returns a list of commands and switches. Here is a screenshot of my environment variables, though for privacy reasons I'll just show the ones that are exclusive to my account.

[Link to environment variables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4yMz.png)

Comment: Have you verified that the file exists : `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe` ? If it exists, please show us your PATH variable.

Answer (score -3):

Oddly enough all was needed was a classic Windows restart to get it working. Apologies.

Comment: Are you the author of the question? Formally you are not. Please see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) Regaining control over the question will allow you to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), possibly your own answer.

Comment: Sometimes too.. we can simply delete the question.